# Send arguments to a function with argv and argc

Tags: function, send

Can someone help me to understand how i need to send the parameters to the function "lora_rf_config" ? Thank you so much !

I try with:

```
char cfgred[7][10]={'lora_rf_config','915000000','10','0','1','8','14'};
lora_rf_config(7,&cfgred);
```

The function that im trying to use is:

```
static void lora_rf_config(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1) {      
        e_printf("OK%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\r\n",  g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Frequency, 
                                             g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Spreadfact,
                                             g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Bandwidth,
                                             g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Codingrate,
                                             g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Preamlen,
                                             g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Powerdbm );
        return;
    } else {
        if (argc != 7) {
            out_error(RAK_ARG_ERR);
            return;
        }
    if (!(CHECK_P2P_FREQ(atoi(argv[1])) &&
             CHECK_P2P_SF(atoi(argv[2])) &&
             CHECK_P2P_BDW(atoi(argv[3])) &&
             CHECK_P2P_CR(atoi(argv[4])) &&
             CHECK_P2P_PREMLEN(atoi(argv[5])) &&
             CHECK_P2P_PWR(atoi(argv[6])))) {
            out_error(RAK_ARG_ERR);
        return;  
      } 

      if (read_partition(PARTITION_0, (char *)&g_lora_config, sizeof(g_lora_config)) < 0) {
          out_error(RAK_RD_CFG_ERR);
          return;
      }

      g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Frequency = atoi(argv[1]);
      g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Spreadfact = atoi(argv[2]);
      g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Bandwidth = atoi(argv[3]);
      g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Codingrate = atoi(argv[4]);
      g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Preamlen = atoi(argv[5]);
      g_lora_config.lorap2p_param.Powerdbm = atoi(argv[6]);
      write_partition(PARTITION_0, (char *)&g_lora_config, sizeof(g_lora_config));
      e_printf("OK\r\n");
    }

    return;
}
```

The error that i got is:

```
..\..\..\src\application\RAK811\app.c(107): error:  #26: too many characters in character constant
  char cfgred[7][10]={'lora_rf_config','915000000','10','0','1','8','14'};
```

I dont have experience with this kind of arguments.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: your String is too long , and you need to use double quote not single quote for strings change the initialization of cfgred to 
: char cfgred[7][16]={"lora_rf_config","915000000","10","0","1","8","14"};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lora_rf_config` expects same arguments than main function: array of pointers to strings, and its length.

Strings in C are pointers to char, where the char buffer they point to has terminating NUL character (if NUL char is missing, then it's not a string, just a character array). In other words, there is no string type in C, but stringiness is determined by the actual data in the char array or buffer. Using `""` string literal creates a string, IOW it adds that terminating NUL char in addition to what you write.

```
// cfgred is array([) of 7 pointers(*) to char.
// Note: string literals are read-only, so you must not modify these
// strings. If you want a modifiable string, this would be a bit more complex,
// but I think this is out of the scope of your question.
char *cfgred[7] = { "lora_rf_config" , "915000000", "10","0", "1", "8", "14"};

// you can get the number of elements in array by dividing its sizeof size (bytes)
// with the size of it's elements in bytes. Just make sure cfgred here is array...
// in the function it is pointer already (arrays get converted to pointers, so
// you can't do this inside the function, you have to do it where you still have
// the original array
int cfgred_len = sizeof cfgred / sizeof(cfgred[0]);

// when you pass array to function, it is automatically converted to pointer, 
// so you must not use & when passing an array like this, otherwise types don't
// match
lora_rf_config(cfgred_len, cfgred);
```

---

As a side note, always turn on compiler warnings... They help you a lot, fix them. For *gcc* and *clagn*, use `-Wall -Wextra`, for Visual Studio use `/W3` or prefereably `/W4`. And then fix any warnings you get, because they are probably something that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: thank you so much ! Now its all okay ! hope you have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization is not done correctly, try changing

```
char cfgred[7][10]={'lora_rf_config','915000000','10','0','1','8','14'};
```

into

```
char cfgred[7][16]={"lora_rf_config","915000000","10","0","1","8","14"};
```

Comment: but when i use that i got:

..\..\..\src\application\RAK811\app.c(109): error:  #167: argument of type "char (*)[7][16]" is incompatible with parameter of type "char **".

the problem is when i do  "lora_rf_config(7,&cfgred); " also